# BigQuery Stored Procedure VS BigQuery Scripts

Tags: optimization, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am able to perform a task of join and aggregation using both Big Query Script and BigQuery Stored Procedure, which is better , which one should be my first choice to execute the task as a BigQuery Script or as a BigQuery Stored Procedure. Is there any advantage or disadvantage of use one over the other.

Comment: Stored procedures will let the the code easy to call and parameterize if needed, further more if the script is frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for BQ but in a lot of databases, Stored procedures parameterization is slower than scripts because stored prcedures can't use the same query plan if parameter change.

In other words, each time the parameter change, the SQL engine recompute the whole query instead using your cache.